# Encrypt and decrypt a string in solidity

Tags: solidity, string, encryption

I would like to write a function to encrypt a string by decreasing it's length then it will be possible to reach the original one too ( two way encryption ).
I don't care about the security. my purpose is just to decrease the length of input string.

Comment: Why do you need to compress an input string? Encryption won't help you to compress strings. To compress efficiently in solidity we will need to know more details about the content of the strings.

Comment: thanks but i think that i found the solution. i my purpose is decrease gas fee in transaction. I think Base64 could help me.

Comment: Base64 doesn't compress things by itself it usually expand them by 4/3.